# Wordpressで追加したカスタム投稿タイプのプレビューボタンのリンク先が変更できない

Tags: wordpress

#### 実現したいこと

WordpressをヘッドレスCMSとして使用しています。作成したカスタム投稿タイプのプレビュー先をNext.jsで作成したフロントにリンクさせたいと思っています。

#### 問題

Wordpressのfunctions.phpに以下のコードを追加したところ、投稿一覧のプレビューボタンはcustom_preview_linkに変更されますが、編集画面のプレビューボタンは変更されません。
どちらも変更する方法はあるのでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

#### functions.php

```
function custom_preview_link($preview_link, $post) {
    global $post_type;
    $preview_url = 'https://sample/api/preview';
    $secret = GRAPHQL_JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY;
    return "{$preview_url}?secret={$secret}&type={$post_type}&id={$post->ID}";
  }
add_filter('preview_post_link', 'custom_preview_link', 10, 2);
```

#### カスタム投稿一覧のプレビューボタン -> 変更された

[image: 投稿一覧のプレビューボタン]

#### カスタム投稿編集画面のプレビューボタン -> 変更されない

[image: 編集画面のプレビューボタン]